# how to remove anchor tag from div which doesnt have any id or class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

[My demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/BPDqc/)

i had code to remove a tag with id or class ..But in this case the anchor tag is generated by wordpress as attachment and it doesnt have any id,class

ANCHOR TAG looks like this

```
<a rel="attachment wp-att-107 slb_group[344] slb slb_internal" 
href="http://santasrecipies.com/myntra-model-5/4783157717_21b8d7199a_b/" >
```

Jquery ATTEMPTS made

```
$('#link').parent().text($('#link').text()).removeChild($('#link'));
```

but this function requires class or id of anchor tag which is absent here...

THE STRUCTURE is

```
<div id="imgContnr">
    <a>
  <div><img></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to remove anchor tag inside div with id `imgContnr`

I have using css by making `pointer-events:none;` but it will affect all the anchor tags which is not right .. 
Somehow i want it to happen using jquery ..Plz look into it ..

Comment: now are you trying to keep the elements within? the anchor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#imgContnr a").remove();
```

This will remove anchor tags whose parent is `imgContnr`.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misunderstood what you're trying to acheive. Although *Just-lewis*' answer works perfect, I'll post my alternative answer to that anyway. This code works the same except it's much shorter

```
$(".imgContnr").find("div").unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks @jude ..But i want contents after that anchor tag..So this nt useful

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer anyway..:)

Comment: I never used the unwrap() will check in to that and add to my arsenal

Answer (score 2):

if your removing the tag all together Jude is correct but if you trying to keep the elements within it'll be as follows:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p7Wy/1/)

```
$("#imgContnr>a").each(function(){
   keeping = $(this).html();
   $(keeping).insertAfter($(this))
   $(this).remove()

});
```

[Heres your demo edited](http://jsfiddle.net/BPDqc/1/)